# Your money has not been debited, you have exceeded the bank limit for this payment. Retry wit a smaller amount

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, upi

I am using UPI in Xamarin android app, and want to receive money using UPI by google pay.

But getting the error, I have tried different amount but getting error.

```
 string amount ="5";
 string transaction_ref_id = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 10) + "UPI";
 string trasaction_ref = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 10);

  using (var uri = new Android.Net.Uri.Builder()
                    .Scheme("upi")
                    .Authority("pay")
                    .AppendQueryParameter("pa", "upiid@anybank")
                    .AppendQueryParameter("pn", "UPI holder name")
                    .AppendQueryParameter("pn", "any name")
                    .AppendQueryParameter("mc", "0000")
                    .AppendQueryParameter("tid", trasaction_ref)
                    .AppendQueryParameter("tr", transaction_ref_id)
                    .AppendQueryParameter("tn", "any notes")
                    .AppendQueryParameter("am", Amount)
                    .AppendQueryParameter("cu", "INR")
                    .Build())
                {
```

Comment: Hope [this](https://www.blueappsoftware.com/google-pay-error-bank-limit-exceeded/) help you

Comment: `"mc", "0000"` : Do you have a valid merchant id/acct?

Comment: @Sniffer - Thanks ! But already checked that link and its no more helpful.

Comment: @SushiHangover - Thanks ! Don't have, but tried with blank as well as removing the MC line of code. But the same error getting.

Comment: @Sheriff You have to have a merchant acct

Comment: @SushiHangover - Can you help me? How to get this?